# C++11 rvalue ссылки + copy constructor = delete

Tags: классы, c++11, vector, методы, rvalue

Всем привет!
Ребят, подскажите лучшее решение:
есть класс **A()**

```
class A()
{
...

A(const A&) = delete;
A& operator=(A&) = delete;

A(A&&)
{
... реализация move semantic
}
A& operator=(A&&)
{
... реализация move semantic
}

A return_one_a(args)
{
// что здесь применить, если есть move конструкторы
// return move(A(...))?
// return A(...)? 
// может вообще сигнатуру сменить и на A* или A& return_one_a(args)
// компилятор говорит, что ипользуется удаленый конструктор
}

std::vector<A> return_many_a(args)
{
std::vector<A> v;
for(int i(0); i > 10; ++i)
{
A a;
v.emplace_back(a) -> ???
v.emplace_back(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)) -> ???
}    
...   
return v;  
} 
...
}
```

Сам вопрос именно по методам return_*..., т.к. код не компилябельный, компилятор ругается на строки "передавания" в вектор (push_back тоже пробовал) или возврата экземпляра класса из функции.

Спасибо!

Comment: Непонятно, что именно у вас компилироваться не хочет... Вот посмотрите пример - https://ideone.com/2aIKdx. Или дайте свой код полностью, что не так...

Comment: код у автора вопроса немного другой:)